# attr_readonly After Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, readonly

Is there was a way to assign `attr_readonly` after update?

```
attr_readonly, on: :update
```

If not, perhaps a method

```
@post.update(content: params[:content])
@post.readonly
```

Comment: What do you try to achieve? This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Comment: @spickermann I am trying to implement a feature that allows users to update only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `readonly?` in that model like this:

```
def readonly?
  super || created_at != updated_at
end
```

Rails checks if a record is readonly before it tries to saves an updated record to the database and would raise an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` exception if the record is marked as readonly. This overridden `readonly?` method protects a record from being changed twice, by returning always `true` if the record was changed at least once (indicated by different timestamp on `updated_at` and `created_at`).

Furthermore this allows you to check in your view `item.readonly?` to hide links to the edit page.

Comment: I don't fully understand what this does. Doesn't `readonly?` only return a boolean value ? @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

you can create a before_update

```
 before_update :forbid_second_update

 def forbid_second_update
   if created_at != updated_at_was
     errors.add :base, "Cannot updated!"
     false
   end
 end
```

first time update will be successful as created_at and updated_at will be same

second time it will fail

or alternatively if you want to lock some attributes and don't want to fail the update, you can just add for eg.

```
 self.email = self.email_was
```

this will override the `email` attribute to its old value

Answer (score 0):

You can add a count into your Model

```
rails g scaffold sport name
rails g migration add_modified_count_to_sports modified_count:integer
```

I'm assigning a default value

```
class AddModifiedCountToSports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :sports, :modified_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end

rake db:migrate
```

On my Sport model I create a before_update sort of validation

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :validate_update_status

  def validate_update_status
    unless self.modified_count.eql?(1)
        #if the field 'modified_count = 0'
        self.modified_count = 1
    else
        errors.add(:name,'You can only modified your account once')
        false
    end#end unless

  end#def

end#class
```

You could also implement the same with a State Machine like gem (i.e. [assm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm))
voilà!